# upgrade from 32 bit vb project to 64 bit

Tags: vb6, excel-addins

I have a visual basic(.vbp) desktop application, actually an excel add-ins, it is in VB 2006 and for 32 bit.

I need to upgrade it so it can work with 64 bit, is it possible to do so and how. please guide I have already searched on all internet.

Comment: There's no such thing as VS 2006.  They went from 2005 to 2008.  I've never created an Excel add-in before but, if it's like other project types, you need to go into the project properties and change the Target Platform to x64.

Comment: i mean visual basic 6.0 , not VB.Net

Comment: As far as I'm aware, VB6 can't handle 64-bit output. You'd have to recreate it from scratch in VB.NET I think. Like I said though, I'm not an expert in this area so don't take my word for it.

Comment: A .vbp means you are using VB6 & VB6 only compiles to 32 bit.  This means your add-in will only work with 32 bit versions of Excel (running on either 32 bit or 64 bit Windows)

Comment: Alternatively, move your code into an actual Excel addin (*.xla, *xlam). Then it will use the host Office's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic 6 (which came out in 1998, not 2006) predates 64-bit Windows development, and certainly predates it being a normal thing. (Windows XP 64-bit for Itanium was released in 2001, and it didn't get much use.) VB6 can only create 32-bit DLLs and Executables. In order to create a 64-bit application, you will need to recreate the program in a more modern programming environment.

Some of the older versions of Visual Basic .NET have [built-in tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648898.aspx) to assist with the migration, which can help with some automated translation from VB6 to VB.NET. But, you'd still need to do some amount of manual work to convert it, and thoroughly test for your use cases.